# how to write a junit test case to run a groovy script and check if it returns a value

Tags: groovy, junit

I have a groovy script which calls a webservice.I want to check if the webservice call is successful running the groovy script using Junit testcase. Please help

Answer (score -1):

You will need to embed the Groovy interpreter in your test code:

```
// call groovy expressions from Java code
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.setVariable("foo", new Integer(2));
GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(binding);

Object value = shell.evaluate("println 'Hello World!'; x = 123; return foo * 10");
assert value.equals(new Integer(20));
assert binding.getVariable("x").equals(new Integer(123));
```

See the [documentation how to embed Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Embedding+Groovy) for details

Comment: import groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader;
import groovy.lang.GroovyObject;

import java.io.File;


public class Test {
 
 
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Throwable{
   
  ClassLoader parent = Test.class.getClassLoader();
  GroovyClassLoader loader = new GroovyClassLoader(parent);
  Class groovyClass = loader.parseClass(new File("src/main/resources/scripts/test.groovy"));

  // let's call some method on an instance
  GroovyObject groovyObject = (GroovyObject) groovyClass.newInstance();
  Object[] arg = {"cvgf","xxx"};
  groovyObject.invokeMethod("run", arg);
  }

}

Comment: I get below error :
Exception in thread "main" org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
unable to resolve class SOAPClient 

    def client = new SOAPClient(url)
                 ^